# Easy pattern replacing on html code

Tags: html, regex

I have a html document with a pattern:

```
<p>1. blablabla...</p>
...
<p>2. some text...</p>
...
<p>3. foo...foo...</p>
```

And I wish I could replace this pattern in the whole document this way:

```
<p class="keep">1. blablabla...</p>
...
<p class="keep">2. some text...</p>
...
<p class="keep">3. foo...foo...</p>
```

How could I do it? I don't know any scripting/programming language, that is why I can't do it.

I'm editing an epub file, so I only know html and css.

**EDIT**: I could use a simple search and replace, but there are a lot of p tags I don't want to replace, only the ones followed by a number and a dot (1. 2. ...)

**EDIT2**: I think I'm not being clear... Here's part of the code:

`<p>1. “Diocese é a porção do Povo de Deus, que se confia a um Bispo, para a apascentar com a colaboração</p>
  <p>do presbitério, de tal modo que, unida ao seu pastor e congregada por ele no Espírito Santo por meio do</p>
  <p>Evangelho e da Eucaristia, constitui uma Igreja particular, na qual está realmente e atua a Igreja de Cristo,</p>
  <p>una, santa, católica e apostólica”. Mais ainda: nela está presente Cristo, por cujo poder a Igreja se unifica.</p>
  <p>Com razão diz Santo Inácio: “Aonde comparecer o Bispo, aí se deve juntar a multidão, tal como, onde estiver</p>
  <p>Jesus Cristo, aí está a Igreja católica.</p>
  <p><br /></p>
  <p>2. À Igreja particular, portanto, corresponde a dignidade da Igreja de Cristo. Esta não é uma associação</p>
  <p>qualquer de homens, que espontaneamente se reúnem para qualquer trabalho comum; é, sim, um dom que</p>
  <p>desce do alto, do Pai das luzes. Tampouco, se deve considerar como simples divisão administrativa do povo</p>
  <p>de Deus, pois ela encerra e manifesta, a seu modo, a natureza da Igreja universal, que jorra, do lado de Cristo</p>
  <p>crucificado, vive e cresce continuamente pela Eucaristia. Ela é a esposa de Cristo, mãe dos fiéis; é, “no lugar</p>
  <p>em que se encontra, o novo Povo chamado por Deus, no Espírito Santo e em grande plenitude”.</p>
  <p><br /></p>
  <p>3. Não se dá nenhuma reunião legítima de fiéis, nem comunidade de altar, que não seja sob o sagrado</p>`

And I want to replace `<p>1. "Diocese` with `<p class="keep">1. Diocese`.
And `<p>2. À Igreja` with `<p class="keep">2. À Igreja`. These are just examples, there are a lot of replacements to do like that.

Comment: Search and replace? Search for "<p>" and replace with "<p class='keep'>"

Comment: Are you editing it in notepad, n++, dreamweaver, or what?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention there a lot of p tags I don't want to replace, only the ones followed bt a number and a dot. I'm using Sublime Text 3, but it don't think it matters... Sometimes I use dreamweaver and sigil.

Comment: @user3399754 What OS are you on? Something Unix-based? A regex + `sed` will probably get this done for you.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. I read some stuff about regex, but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with the command line in Linux. Here is what I worked for me:

I created a test.html containing your example html:

```
<p>1. “Diocese é a porção do Povo de Deus, que se confia a um Bispo, para a apascentar com a colaboração</p>
  <p>do presbitério, de tal modo que, unida ao seu pastor e congregada por ele no Espírito Santo por meio do</p>
  <p>Evangelho e da Eucaristia, constitui uma Igreja particular, na qual está realmente e atua a Igreja de Cristo,</p>
  <p>una, santa, católica e apostólica”. Mais ainda: nela está presente Cristo, por cujo poder a Igreja se unifica.</p>
  <p>Com razão diz Santo Inácio: “Aonde comparecer o Bispo, aí se deve juntar a multidão, tal como, onde estiver</p>
  <p>Jesus Cristo, aí está a Igreja católica.</p>
  <p><br /></p>
  <p>2. À Igreja particular, portanto, corresponde a dignidade da Igreja de Cristo. Esta não é uma associação</p>
  <p>qualquer de homens, que espontaneamente se reúnem para qualquer trabalho comum; é, sim, um dom que</p>
  <p>desce do alto, do Pai das luzes. Tampouco, se deve considerar como simples divisão administrativa do povo</p>
  <p>de Deus, pois ela encerra e manifesta, a seu modo, a natureza da Igreja universal, que jorra, do lado de Cristo</p>
  <p>crucificado, vive e cresce continuamente pela Eucaristia. Ela é a esposa de Cristo, mãe dos fiéis; é, “no lugar</p>
  <p>em que se encontra, o novo Povo chamado por Deus, no Espírito Santo e em grande plenitude”.</p>
  <p><br /></p>
  <p>3. Não se dá nenhuma reunião legítima de fiéis, nem comunidade de altar, que não seja sob o sagrado</p>
```

Then ran this command line. The first line looks for <p> followed by one or more digits and a period and replaces the <p> with <p class="keep">. The command applies those changes to the content of test.html and saves them into test2.html. The second line merely outputs the changes and you can see the results:

```
$ sed -E 's/<p>([0-9]+\.)/<p class="keep">\1/' test.html > test2.html
$ cat test2.html
<p class="keep">1. “Diocese é a porção do Povo de Deus, que se confia a um Bispo, para a apascentar com a colaboração</p>
  <p>do presbitério, de tal modo que, unida ao seu pastor e congregada por ele no Espírito Santo por meio do</p>
  <p>Evangelho e da Eucaristia, constitui uma Igreja particular, na qual está realmente e atua a Igreja de Cristo,</p>
  <p>una, santa, católica e apostólica”. Mais ainda: nela está presente Cristo, por cujo poder a Igreja se unifica.</p>
  <p>Com razão diz Santo Inácio: “Aonde comparecer o Bispo, aí se deve juntar a multidão, tal como, onde estiver</p>
  <p>Jesus Cristo, aí está a Igreja católica.</p>
  <p><br /></p>
  <p class="keep">2. À Igreja particular, portanto, corresponde a dignidade da Igreja de Cristo. Esta não é uma associação</p>
  <p>qualquer de homens, que espontaneamente se reúnem para qualquer trabalho comum; é, sim, um dom que</p>
  <p>desce do alto, do Pai das luzes. Tampouco, se deve considerar como simples divisão administrativa do povo</p>
  <p>de Deus, pois ela encerra e manifesta, a seu modo, a natureza da Igreja universal, que jorra, do lado de Cristo</p>
  <p>crucificado, vive e cresce continuamente pela Eucaristia. Ela é a esposa de Cristo, mãe dos fiéis; é, “no lugar</p>
  <p>em que se encontra, o novo Povo chamado por Deus, no Espírito Santo e em grande plenitude”.</p>
  <p><br /></p>
  <p class="keep">3. Não se dá nenhuma reunião legítima de fiéis, nem comunidade de altar, que não seja sob o sagrado</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many text editors have a find/replace functionality. In Sublime Text 2 it is Find > Replace.

Comment: I forgot to mention I don't want to replace all of the p tags, only the ones following the pattern above.

Comment: You aren't limited to using the tag. At least in Sublime Text 2, you could enter the entire: `<p>1. blablabla...</p>` I'm playing with it in Sublime Text 2 now and the only problem I'm encountering is trying to find/replace all three paragraph elements at once. It doesn't return a match because of the whitespace in the markup, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard - all you have to do is press Ctrl + F or Ctrl + H or click on Replace or Find Button on your file editor.

Then find

```
<p>
```

and replace with

```
<p class="keep">
```

That's it :)

Comment: Please read second EDIT, it's not only find and replace, I'm not a newbie with sublime or basics on text editing.

Comment: hmm all comes with this format 1. 2. 3. ? can u post complete code ?

Comment: The parts I want to replace follow that pattern, but there are some p tags I don't to replace. The full code is really big (it's a book), but there are some headings only.